# How to call a Variable inside another variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

This variable will show the currently playing song's name.
 `"' . $song->name . '"`

What I'm trying to do is call the function of the song name, but in a different code location, which is the one down below:

```
if ( ! $in_popup )
            $html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . 'player/?playlist_id=' . $playlist_id . '&amp;iframe=false"></a>';
            $html .= '<div class="playlist-type">   

                    <span class="song_title">SONG NAME HERE</span>

        <!-- End -->';
```

But I can't seem to sort it out myself, as it gives me 500 Internal Server Error if I simply just place the variable somewhere in this code.

Comment: Could you show a little more code? The declaration of your function and how you call the function.

Comment: The first thing you need to do when you got 500 error should be finding some information in the error log.

Comment: @Samyoul Here is how the function is originally declared http://pastebin.com/nsKkE9M2

Comment: I would concur with Young. The specific error itself would be a lot more helpful in solving your issue. It will tell you where the issue lies and what the problem is.